# Can A Database Transaction Have Different Session IDs?

Tags: sql-server, transaction

I am just trying to troubleshoot an issue and was it seems that one of my spids is associated with an open transaction.  Just wondering if that spid would be used for other queries in the transactions too?  Or how can I find what other queries are running under that transaction?

Thanks!

Comment: In case of parallelism same SPID can be used to do multiple tasks. If [MARS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/multiple-active-result-sets-mars) is active single session can run multiple batches.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "_other queries in the transactions _", but with regards to the title, while the answer is _generally_ "no", there is a case where it should be possible: distributed transactions. Are you using Distributed Transactions?

Comment: Thanks - I am just trying to trouble shoot an issue and I have a  spid for example '100' that is running a pretty basic query and it is part of a transaction but it is causing blocking for about 20 other sessions.  Just trying to find out if I should be looking at other queries with the same SPID or if was possible that other queries in the transaction could be using different SPID.    I have banging my head trying to figure out an ERP blocking issue when the lead blocker is a pretty straightforward query.  Thanks!

Comment: @DanielPaduck the simplicity of the query can be entirely irrelevant. It all depends on what is being locked and why, etc. Did you look in `sys.dm_exec_requests` to see if that SPID is being blocked by something, and/or `SELECT * FROM sys.dm_tran_locks WHERE request_session_id = {SPID}` to see what exactly is being locked and/or if that SPID is currently executing a query that doesn't include the locked object and/or what the WAIT_TYPE is for that SPID? There could be a variety of explanations. If connection pooling is used, could be an orphaned transaction (but maybe not for 20 minutes).

Comment: Hi - I am using sp_WhoIsActive and do not see anything blocking that query. It is the lead blocker in this chain. The thing that it is weird is that when I run sp_whoisactive it says that reads is 22,368 but when I run the query individual the reads is only 4.  Thus, is it possible for the application to just be an infinite loop running the same query?